# Can't find my html pages

Tags: html, amazon-s3, gatsby

I'm not sure if I'm using Gatsby in the right way.

I have downloaded and installed Gatsby following the tutorial here:
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/

Then I have used the Gatsby Dimension starter with the command:

```
$gatsby new gatsby-starter-dimension https://github.com/ChangoMan/gatsby-starter-dimension
```

I have edited the *Main.js* file in *src* directory and used the commands *gatsby build* and *gatsby serve*.
I can see my pages on http://localhost:9000/

But if I open the index.html file in the *public* folder, I can only see a black page.

Which files I'm supposed to upload to S3 if I want to build a static web site?

thanks

Comment: You should start by running `gatsby develop`, which will run a server that serves the React components allowing you to debug your application.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Try to reproduce with the following commands:

#gatsby new gatsby-starter-dimension https://github.com/ChangoMan/gatsby-starter-dimension
#cd gatsby-starter-dimension
#gatsby develop
#gatsby build
#gatsby serve

Then try to open this file with your browser: gatsby-starter-dimension\public\index.html The page is all black.

Comment: I ran the starter command you provided and then ran `gatsby develop` and it loads up fine. Ditto on `gatsby build; gatsby serve`. https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/1o0X2b0S3G1s2n2q4330/Screen%20Shot%202018-05-25%20at%2012.15.20%20PM.png?v=ad302aea